# Does there exist $A \subset \mathbb{R}$, satisfying the following three conditions?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Does there exist $A \subset \mathbb{R}$, satisfying the following three conditions:

1)$\forall x \in A$ $\mu(A \cap [x - 1; x + 1]) > 1$

2)$\forall x \notin A$ $\mu(A \cap [x - 1; x + 1]) < 1$

3)$A \notin \{\mathbb{R}, \emptyset\}$

$\mu$ stands here for Lebesgue measure.

It is not hard to see, that if $A$ satisfies these conditions, then $\mathbb{R} \setminus A$, $-A$ and $x + A$, where $x$ is an arbitrary real number, satisfy these conditions too. Also, if $A$ and $B$ both satisfy these conditions and $\inf |A -B| \geq 2$, then $A \cup B$ satisfies those conditions too. However, that does not seem to be very helpful.

Another not very helpful fact is, that if $A$ satisfies these conditions and $(x ; x+1) \subset A$, then $\mu((x-1; x) \cap A) > 0$. And it again tells us nothing about existence of such subsets.

Comment: What happens at the boundary of $A$? If the function $x \mapsto \mu(A\cap[x-1,x+1])$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$, then by the intermediate value theorem, no $A$ can satisfy these conditions.

Comment: @Karl, I see now. And that function is indeed continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ as $\forall \epsilon > 0$ and $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $|\mu(A \cap [x - 1, x + 1]) - \mu(A \cap [x + \epsilon -1; x + \epsilon + 1]| \leq 2\epsilon$.

Comment: @Karl, you could have posted this as an answer, instead of comment. In that case, I would have had no choice but to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it does not.

$x \mapsto \mu(A\cap [x - 1; x + 1])$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ as $\forall \epsilon > 0$ and $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $|\mu(A\cap [x - 1; x + 1]) - \mu(A\cap [x + \epsilon - 1; x + \epsilon + 1])| \leq 2\epsilon$. Thus, by intermediate value theorem if $A \notin \{\mathbb{R}, \emptyset\}$, then $\exists x \in \mathbb{R}$, such that $\mu(A\cap [x - 1; x + 1]) = 1$

Comment: Shouldn't that last value be $1,$ not $\frac {1}{2}$ ?